# select and remove SQL records with a timestamp difference < 1 day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select or remove records from badge-records that have a date difference less than 1 day
If 2 or more records exists within 24hours all of them has to be removed but one. (the first or last one, this is not important)
A select query to find them is ok, so I can remove them manually.

Only records of the same badge number must be compared and removed.

Is this possible using TSQL ?

Example:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| TimeStamp        | Badge        |
+------------------+--------------+
| 19-10-2021 10:18 | Badge1       |
| 20-10-2021 12:18 | Badge1       |
| 22-10-2021 13:23 | Badge1       |  
| 22-10-2021 11:18 | Badge1       |  <--- remove
| 22-10-2021 13:18 | Badge1       |  <--- remove
| 23-10-2021 14:18 | Badge1       |
| 21-10-2021 09:18 | Badge12      |
| 23-10-2021 10:18 | Badge12      |
| 23-10-2021 23:18 | Badge12      |  <--- remove
| 25-10-2021 12:18 | Badge12      |
+------------------+---------+----+
```

Comment: To clarify, does "within 24 hours" mean timestamps with the same calendar date (both on date 23-10-2021) OR timestamps less than 24 hours apart (like **22-10**-2021 23:23 and **23-10**-2021 01:04).  *"...A select query to find them is ok.."* Please post your current query.

Comment: I mean timestamps less than 24 hours apart (like 22-10-2021 23:23 and 23-10-2021 01:04)  - I don't have a query right now, I have no idea how to do this. i think a join with the same table can do the trick?

Comment: I can't think of a way that this could be solved with a non-iterative statement. The status of record 6 depends on the status of the previous three, which in turn may depend on the status of records prior to that. I think a cursor loop that steps through the records and tracks the latest retained TimeStamp value (per badge) may be the best approach at identifying each record disposition.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @SOS,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=296b97685b544d67b05d15c94c0dea4d
did the trick, I changed the last sql in

```
    ...
    select * from YourTable where timestamp not in 
(
SELECT   tbl.TimeStamp
FROM   dateCte cte
       CROSS APPLY (
           SELECT TOP 1 * 
           FROM   YourTable base
           WHERE  base.Badge = cte.Badge
           AND    base.TimeStamp >= cte.RangeStart
           AND    base.TimeStamp < cte.RangeEnd
       ) tbl
 )
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)
;
```

This way i could see and remove the unwanted records.
If you post the solution i can accept it as solved

Comment: Thanks but I deliberately did NOT post it as an answer yet as I suspected better options were possible ;-).  (The query is VERY resource intensive, so not the best answer for every case.  Plus I was hoping someone else would come up with a more performant and elegant answer.) That said, are you using this for a "one off" job or something regular? Also, approximately how many records?

Comment: yes, it's used for a "one off" job to see persons who enter more than once  within a time frame. This is for an entrance system but it's forbidden to enter again within 24hrs.  We just need to see the problem users... record count is 300k records ..

Comment: Ah, okay. Definitely check out the comments and updated fiddles as @TN may have found some edge cases that are detected differently by the cursor and CTE approach, with the CTE missing some.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the chained dependencies of any given record status on the statuses of all of the preceding records (with the same Badge value), I don't think there is a single statement solution.  The following uses a cursor to step through the records while tracking the prior retained values.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, TimeStamp DATETIME, Badge VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data
VALUES
    ('2021-10-19 10:18', 'Badge1'),
    ('2021-10-20 12:18', 'Badge1'),
    ('2021-10-22 13:23', 'Badge1'),  
    ('2021-10-22 11:18', 'Badge1'), -- remove ??? (prior record is out of sequence)
    ('2021-10-22 13:18', 'Badge1'), -- remove
    ('2021-10-23 14:18', 'Badge1'),
    ('2021-10-21 09:18', 'Badge12'),
    ('2021-10-23 10:18', 'Badge12'),
    ('2021-10-23 23:18', 'Badge12'), -- remove
    ('2021-10-25 12:18', 'Badge12')

DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @TimeStamp DATETIME
DECLARE @Badge VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @PriorTimeStamp DATETIME = NULL
DECLARE @PriorBadge VARCHAR(100) = NULL

DECLARE Csr CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Id, Timestamp, Badge
    FROM @Data
    ORDER BY Badge, Timestamp, Id
    --ORDER BY Badge, Id
OPEN Csr

FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @Id, @TimeStamp, @Badge
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @Badge = @PriorBadge AND @TimeStamp < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @PriorTimeStamp)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM @Data WHERE CURRENT OF CSR
    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- Keep
        SET @PriorBadge = @Badge
        SET @PriorTimeStamp = @TimeStamp
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @Id, @TimeStamp, @Badge
END

CLOSE Csr
DEALLOCATE Csr

SELECT *
FROM @data
ORDER BY ID
```

Results:

| Id | TimeStamp | Badge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-19 10:18:00.000 | Badge1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-20 12:18:00.000 | Badge1 |
| 4 | 2021-10-22 11:18:00.000 | Badge1 |
| 6 | 2021-10-23 14:18:00.000 | Badge1 |
| 7 | 2021-10-21 09:18:00.000 | Badge12 |
| 8 | 2021-10-23 10:18:00.000 | Badge12 |
| 10 | 2021-10-25 12:18:00.000 | Badge12 |

Note that the '2021-10-22 13:23' value was retained and the '2021-10-22 11:18' value was deleted due to the ascending dates. If original data order matters, swap out the `ORDER BY` clauses above.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3136cbf2578aeea717c9313412c46ea) for a demo.

Comment: [This db<.fiddle>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=507933c7a8ae38ab214a1ec580b6332b) includes additional test data that demonstrates the ripple effect that a small change to one value can affect the results of all following records for the same badge.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT#1]  The op didn't have it in their original post but she's using 2008.  The following solution uses LAG, which isn't available until 2012.  I also added a tag to the original post so no one else has the same problem.

**[EDIT#2]  I've apparently misread the clarification that the OP posted as the 3rd comment in the original post.  My interpretation was to delete any row that was less than 24 hours from the previous row, which the code below does. By the OPs post that says what worked by @SOS, it would appear the OP meant to examine a date and then remove any rows after that that are < 24 hours away and only then see what the next date to examine is.  The code below doesn't do that.**

I agree with @TN above... You have an out of order date and I'm going to treat this as if the related removal is actually a mistake on your part.

First, here's my version of a test table...

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable
;
GO
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy
;
 SELECT  TimeStamp = CONVERT(DATETIME,v.TimeStamp)
        ,v.Badge
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES
         ('19-10-2021 10:18','Badge1' )
        ,('20-10-2021 12:18','Badge1' )
        ,('22-10-2021 13:23','Badge1' )-- This is the row that should be removed instead of the one below according to the specs you wrote. 
        ,('22-10-2021 11:18','Badge1' )-- remove ??? (prior record is out of sequence, so not)
        ,('22-10-2021 13:18','Badge1' )-- remove
        ,('23-10-2021 14:18','Badge1' )
        ,('21-10-2021 09:18','Badge12')
        ,('23-10-2021 10:18','Badge12')
        ,('23-10-2021 23:18','Badge12') -- remove
        ,('25-10-2021 12:18','Badge12')
        )v(TimeStamp,Badge)
;
```

Next, a bit of a demo using LAG(OVER) to solve for the number of minutes between the current row and the previous row... we don't need any form of recursion for this.

```
 SELECT *
        ,DeltaMinutes = DATEDIFF(mi,LAG(TimeStamp,1,DATEADD(dd,-2,TimeStamp)) OVER (PARTITION BY Badge ORDER BY TimeStamp),TimeStamp) 
   FROM #TestTable
;
```

That produces the following.  Notice the DeltaMinutes column and the correct sort order.  The row highlighted in Blue is the row that was out of order.

[image: Results From Above]

After that, all we have to do is select the rows that have DeltaMinutes >= 1440 minutes, which is the number of minutes in a day.  If you change the >= to a < , then it will display the rows that are less than 1 day from the previous row.

```
   WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *
        ,DeltaMinutes = DATEDIFF(mi,LAG(TimeStamp,1,DATEADD(dd,-2,TimeStamp)) OVER (PARTITION BY Badge ORDER BY TimeStamp),TimeStamp) 
   FROM #TestTable
)
 SELECT TimeStamp,Badge
   FROM cte 
  WHERE DeltaMinutes >= 1440 --Minutes in a day.
  ORDER BY  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Badge,6,5)) --Sort badge numbers in numeric instead of string order.
           ,TimeStamp
;
```

The result from that looks like this...

[image]

Of course, LAG is only available from 2012 and onward.  If you're using 2008/2008R2 or less, there's another non-recursive trick we can use.

**And, with all of that, I have to say that I think your spec may be incorrect, as @TN implies.  I think what you really want is to keep the first row (for example) and remove all rows from the output that are within 1440 minutes of THAT row. The next row that's at least 1440 minutes after that first row would become the new "anchor" row and all rows less than 1440 minutes after THAT row would be removed from the output.  If that's what you really meant, then post back and we'll solve that problem in a similar manner.**

***And with the current data, you probably won't see any difference but if the data changes, you will.***

Comment: *..think your spec may be incorrect...* I'm leaning that way myself. I don't see how it can be solved without an iterative approach like a cursor (undesirable).  Your attempts at using LAG() got much close than mine :) But I think the logic may still drop some records that should be preserved, example "Badge100".  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7473e88f4cf329598a20e280264307dd  While I don't love cursors, that approach does seem to return the expected rows https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e2801535dc26cb33260256b0bd9f5af

Comment: Doing it the way we're both thinking, can still be done with a non-iterative approach using "return to 0 running totals" where the running total counts up to a limit and, once that limit is reached, resets to 0 and starts over.

Comment: Yeah, I briefly considered something like that yesterday, but couldn't come up with anything that worked with this kind of time range, since it's not fixed and not cumulative like a typical amount SUM(). Maybe I was too tired... The only alternative I could think of was a set based loop, which is still iterative, but not quite as granular as a cursor.

Comment: I just had an idea. Using cte's to generate 24 intervals seems to work without iterating https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=296b97685b544d67b05d15c94c0dea4d

Comment: That could work.  If you have a Tally Function to do the gen, the CTE would be even simpler.

Comment: I just had a look at your db<>fiddle.  You used a recursive CTE (rCTE) to do the gen.... I strongly advise against that even for small row counts.  A good Tally or Nums function would avoid all the unnecessary reads that rCTE's generate even for small row counts.  It's one of those things that helps avoid the SQL "Death by a Thousand Cuts" in the big picture.  The rest looks like the right idea but the equal intervals will rarely match up perfectly with the data.  If something starts half way through an interval, it might be in error by 30 minutes.  And thanks for the code posting!

Comment: Yeah, agreed on cte's.  Still hoping someone can make things work with lead() or lag()!  I'm not sure I follow you on the last part though i.e. "might be in error by 30 minutes".  As the "which record to remove" requirement seemed flexible.  Have an example that falls into that category?  (No rush or anything. I just find this an interesting problem to tackle.)

Comment: @Jeff the sql version I use is 2008R2, i receive the error 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name.  The idea to have the records to be removed as the result of the query is fine.  can this also be done in 2008 with Row_number?

Comment: @Jef, it doesn't matter of the first of last row(s) is/are removed, i just have to end up with a table where all timestamps differ more than 1440 mins for one badge.

Comment: The code I posted does what you asked with the 1440 minutes requirement between adjacent entries that you mention.  My concern is that, requirement is actually in error because, in theory, all of the entries for a given badge could be 1439 minutes apart (for example) and so, even if you had 10,000 such entries over years of badge entries for a given badge, only one of them would ever be returned.

Comment: @JeffModen - You mentioned "return to 0 running totals" above. That's new to me (beyond the reset that occurs based on partition-by). Could you point me to an example please?

Comment: @TN - Here's one example from StackOverflow ( stackoverflow.com/questions/31481941/… ). The trouble is, it won't work for 2008 and it's too slow for my liking. It takes 6.7 seconds on a million rows. I have an old method that will work as for back as SQL Version 7 that I'm trying to adapt that does those same million row in only 673ms.   It also doesn't appear to actually function correctly for what we want.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT#1]  I've apparently misread the clarification that the OP posted as the 3rd comment in the original post.  My interpretation was to delete any row that was less than 24 hours from the previous row, which the code below does. By the OPs post that says what worked by @SOS, it would appear the OP meant to examine a date and then remove any rows after that that are < 24 hours away and only then see what the next date to examine is.  The code below doesn't do that.**

Here's an answer that will work in 2008.  If you have the appropriate unique index on TimeStamp and Badge (or even vice versa), it won't have to even do a sort.  In either case, this is a lot faster and less resource intensive because it only does two table scans rather than triangular joins.  Don't forget to change the name of the table to suit your actual table name.

```
   WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT  RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Badge ORDER BY TimeStamp)
        ,TimeStamp
        ,Badge
   FROM #YourTable
)
 SELECT  cur.TimeStamp
        ,cur.Badge
     -- ,prv.* -- Uncomment to learn more
     -- ,Delta  = DATEDIFF(mi,prv.TimeStamp,cur.TimeStamp) --Uncomment to learn more
        ,Action = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi,prv.TimeStamp,cur.TimeStamp)<1440 THEN 'Remove' ELSE 'Keep' END
   FROM CTE cur
   LEFT JOIN CTE prv ON cur.Badge = prv.Badge AND cur.RowNum = prv.RowNum + 1
  WHERE ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi,prv.TimeStamp,cur.TimeStamp),1440) < 1440 --Comment this out to return all entries to learn.
;
```

Results from above:
[image]

p.s.  There's no way that I would actually remove the rows because they're a part of "history".

Comment: Agreed it's more efficient, but doesn't this version still have the same issue as [the LAG version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71262732/8895292)? i.e. It picks up/drops some of the wrong records https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=295d4766391fb0e9b0947961265ce086

Comment: The lag version did what the OP wanted.  So does this one.  If you're talking about basing it on the difference of two adjacent rows, then, yes, they both have the problem that you and I talked about for being the wrong way to do things.  In other words, the bad 10,000 row example will occur in the LAG code and in this code.

Comment: Well, I guess that's my point. My interpretation of what they actually wanted *is* based on the difference between rows. So from that POV, it doesn't achieve that. Not saying that *I* know how to do it efficiently, just that I don't think this result is exactly what they're after. Maybe I'm missing something though. Anyway, at this point, I guess it's up to them whether it meets their criteria or not (-:.

Comment: Typo correction:  *"...this result is not exactly what they're after..."*

Comment: Except that I have an indicator column to "Remove", is it not the same result that you have on db<>fiddle?

Comment: No.  Run my original fiddle. Then use the same sample data and run the above query. Then compare the results.  You'll see they're different.

Comment: Uncomment the two comment out pieces of code, comment out the WHERE clause and look at the Delta column to see why I disagree. :D

Comment: Yeah, I'd already done that, which is how I know the results aren't the same :-) But I did take another look, and realized it's closer than I thought, but still an edge case it misses https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e4f810c64bd9e9bc94ba2df07fffd1ce . That said, yours is much more efficient than my fiddle, so props for that!

Comment: @SOS - Ok. I see what you mean now for Badge100. I've added edits at the top of both of my submittals to explain. I'm going to try to find the time to correct both submittals, as well. As a bit of a sidebar for Badge1, you gave the OP what she asked for rows to remove. I'm just not sure that the rows being out of temporal order according to the TimeStamp column is correct. And thanks for the feedback and your honesty about performance. This has been interesting and it's been good to meet you.

Comment: FYI - I generated some additional test data that demonstrates how a small change to early records ripples through the results of all later records and applied it to the [cursor based](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72f64420855c20870b04b55c7c95c5a7), [recursive CTE based](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=565c53ee93218b08947935ee7d5155bb), and [LAG-based](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ded7e21f424e5d8c1ee2780bb8e3b5a) solutions. Each yielded different results. (continued)

Comment: (continued) The LAG based solution dropped rows that should have started a new 24 hour period. The recursive CTE solution didn't seem to handle the odd gap case for Badge 4. I think a recursive CTE approach may be possible, as I think it should be possible to duplicate iterative logic, but it can't be based on consecutive 24 hours windows.

Comment: @JeffModen - Yeah, nice to meet you too. It's always fun to have an honest discussion about sql ... without any ego ... "Just the facts ma'am" (from Dragnet) ;-)

Comment: @TN - Thanks for that. I was thinking the 24 hour windows would work if it was based off the 1st timestamp, but it sounds like "no".  I've got some stuff to do now, but ll take a look at your tests later.